# How to retrive highest time spent from array of object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object in which I have calculated **sessions(time spent) of particular ip**.  I have calculated spent time in hh:mm:ss format so that it will easy to understand.

```
[ { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 06:04:49 GMT',
    end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 06:12:22 GMT',
    total_spend: '00:07:27' },
  { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:58:18 GMT',
    end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:59:09 GMT',
    total_spend: '00:00:50' },
  { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 09:28:00 GMT',
    end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 09:59:46 GMT',
    total_spend: '00:31:46' } ]
```

now I want the **highest of total_spend from above array** i.e

> maximum time spent compare to all object that should be '00:31:46' (31
>   minutes, 46 seconds)

I can't understand how I'll compare this as all comparison in this format so far I've seen was converted to date then compared. Either I can convert it into ms and then I should compare. Is there any other way to execute this?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: nah... I don't want to use any other package for only this purpose..any other suggestions? @ritaj

Comment: So just convert them into miliseconds manually.

Comment: You will only be able to get seconds from the strings in the format you have and that's all that is displayed, if you want higher resolution just the EPOCH timestamp since 1970 which is in milliseconds.  Its also much easier working with milliseconds, just (latest - first) will give you the difference then convert this back to a time string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just compare the strings? If you do 'stringA' < 'stringB', JavaScript will compare the two strings as if they were to be sorted alphabetically, based on unicode values, so a lower time will be correctly evaluated as "less than" a higher time.

Like so:

```
const sessions = [ 
  { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 06:04:49 GMT',
    end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 06:12:22 GMT',
    total_spend: '00:07:27' },
  { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:58:18 GMT',
    end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:59:09 GMT',
    total_spend: '00:00:50' },
  { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 09:28:00 GMT',
    end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 09:59:46 GMT',
    total_spend: '00:31:46' } 
]

let highest = '00:00:00';
for (let session of sessions) {
  if (session.total_spend > highest) {
    highest = session.total_spend
  }
}
console.log(highest)
```

Comment: waoo!!... I thought string comparison wouldn't work!..tqsm

Answer (score 0):

You could `sort` descending *sessions* array by taking difference from `start` and `end` properties and then just access the first element.

```js
let sessions = [ { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 06:04:49 GMT', end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 06:12:22 GMT', total_spend: '00:07:27' }, { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:58:18 GMT', end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:59:09 GMT', total_spend: '00:00:50' }, { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 09:28:00 GMT', end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 09:59:46 GMT', total_spend: '00:31:46' } ]
sessions.sort((a,b) => (new Date(b.end) - new Date(b.start)) - (new Date(a.end) - new Date(a.start)));
console.log(sessions[0].total_spend);
```

Another approach could be using `reduce` method.

```js
let sessions = [ { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 06:04:49 GMT', end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 06:12:22 GMT', total_spend: '00:07:27' }, { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:58:18 GMT', end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 07:59:09 GMT', total_spend: '00:00:50' }, { start: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 09:28:00 GMT', end: 'Thu, 10 Jan 2019 09:59:46 GMT', total_spend: '00:31:46' } ]

let index = sessions.reduce((iMax, x, i, arr) => (new Date(x.end) - new Date(x.start)) > new Date(arr[iMax].end) - new Date(arr[iMax].start) ? i : iMax, 0);

console.log(sessions[index].total_spend);
```

Comment: Better to use `.reduce` and `Math.max`

Comment: tq for your quick response and effort :)